# Passing dynamic parameter to Native function in Kusto

Tags: azure, function, kql

I have a native function with below schema

```
    let x= myNativeFunc (AccName :string, RG: string, Sub: string, StartTinme : datetime, EndTime : datetime, Threshold :int);
```

```
Now I have multiple set of data to pass to this function such as below :
```

```
  AccName = (acc1,acc2)  RG = (rg1,rg2) sub = (sub1,sub2)
```

Rest values can be hardcoded. Is there a way to pass such parameter to my native function with dynamic variable or using loop

Unable to use range or dynamic function. Need help on that else if there is any other way to achieve, that also would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are giving string you need to send only string as input like below:

```
let x = (key:string, value:string)
{
 let r= strcat(key,value);
 print r
}; 
let c= x("rithwik","bojja");
c
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

If you want to send dynamic data then you need to make the type as dynamic like below:

```
let x = (key:dynamic, value:dynamic)
{
 let r= strcat(key,value);
 print r
}; 
let c= x(dynamic('rithwik,bojja'),dynamic('rithwik,bojja'));
c
```

**`Output:`**

[image]